# ECGenParameterSpec unknown curve name 'secp256k1'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have project which creates private and public keys. I want to encrypt them with ecdsa, because of this I use ECGenParameterSpec with 'secp256k1' parameter but this gives error. If I change it with 'secp256r1' there is no problem. Here is my code to generate keys:

```
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");

        ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = newECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
        keyGen.initialize(ecSpec);

        KeyPair kp = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PublicKey pub = kp.getPublic();
        PrivateKey pvt = kp.getPrivate();

        ECPrivateKey epvt = (ECPrivateKey)pvt;
        String sepvt = adjustTo64(epvt.getS().toString(16));
        System.out.println("s[" + sepvt.length() + "]: " + sepvt);

        ECPublicKey epub = (ECPublicKey)pub;
        ECPoint pt = epub.getW();
        String sx = adjustTo64(pt.getAffineX().toString(16));
        String sy = adjustTo64(pt.getAffineY().toString(16));
        String bcPub = sx + sy;
        System.out.println("bcPub: " + bcPub);

        return bcPub;
```

To adjust 64 bit

```
        static private String adjustTo64(String s) {
          switch(s.length()) {
          case 62: return "00" + s;
          case 63: return "0" + s;
          case 64: return s;
          default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a valid key: " +s);
          }
        }
```

When I use secp256k1 it gives this error:

```
05-01 12:20:46.066 17297-17297/com.sikke.app W/System.err: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: unknown curve name: secp256k1
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECKeyPairGenerator.initialize(OpenSSLECKeyPairGenerator.java:113)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:439)
    at com.sikke.app.AppHelper.getEcdsa(AppHelper.java:125)
    at com.sikke.app.activities.AccountActivity.onCreate(AccountActivity.java:59)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)05-01 12:20:46.067 17297-17297/com.sikke.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long search, I found a solution for my project. You should add this code in your project to change security provider.

```
 Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

to add this code you should this library: `prov-1.58.0.0`